# How to set align of elements to center with css?

Tags: html, css

I try to set align of elements that exist into div tag with dark class to center.I have an image  and a div element with img-circle class  that most be in center (vertical,horizontal). Please advice.
See Demo  on

> http://jsfiddle.net/hmahdavi921/94nfxyz8/

css:

```
 .img-circle img {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 6px solid #b9b7b7;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dark {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;

}

div.dark:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

div.dark:hover:after {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="dark img-circle">
    <div>

        <div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-circle">
            <h3>نام من</h3>
            <p>توضیحات من </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
        <!-- Start_Module_428 --><div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://www.dnnskin.net/portals/631/team3.png" height="279" width="446">
</div>

</div><!-- End_Module_428 --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need to change position of this tags

```
 <h3>نام من</h3>
            <p>توضیحات من </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
```

do it.no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution
1- add new div  with absolute positionfor

```
        <h3>نام من</h3>
        <p>توضیحات من </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
```

new code

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 100%;text-align: center">
        <h3>نام من</h3>
        <p>توضیحات من </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
</div>
```

2- add style tyle="text-align: center;" to div with id dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent

```
<div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal" style="text-align: center;">
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/94nfxyz8/5/)

Comment: OK. Image placed on the center of page  but new div most placed on center of page like image .If you need to change position of new div and it's elements you can do it

Comment: juste add :    width: 100%;text-align: center; to the new div

Answer (score 1):

Now used to this css as like this .

```
.Normal{
position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:50%;margin-top:-145px;bottom:0;text-align:center;
}
html body, html, .dark{height:100%;}
```

**Demo**

```css
.Normal{
position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:50%;margin-top:-145px;bottom:0;text-align:center;
}
html body, html{height:100%;}

.img-circle img {
    border: 6px solid #b9b7b7;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dark {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    
}

div.dark:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

div.dark:hover:after {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark img-circle">
    <div>

        <div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-circle">
            <h3>نام من</h3>
            <p>توضیحات من </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
        <!-- Start_Module_428 --><div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
 <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
 <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://www.dnnskin.net/portals/631/team3.png" height="279" width="446">
</div>

</div><!-- End_Module_428 --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## ================================

Updated Demo

```css
.Normal, .imgText{
position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:50%;margin-top:-145px;bottom:0;text-align:center;
}
.imgText{
    z-index:9;top:50%;margin-top:-57px;
    
}
html body, html{height:100%;}

.img-circle img {
    border: 6px solid #b9b7b7;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.dark {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    
}

div.dark:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

div.dark:hover:after {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark img-circle">
    <div>

        <div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane" class="img-circle">
        <!-- Start_Module_428 -->
            
            <div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
   <div class="imgText">   
            <h3>نام من</h3>
            <p>توضیحات من </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
  </div>
             <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
                 <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://www.dnnskin.net/portals/631/team3.png" height="279" width="446" />
                </div>

        </div><!-- End_Module_428 -->
            
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case position of  h3 ,p and button tags are left .This elements most be on center of image

Comment: Do you means p, h3 and button tag also cener of image if yes than you cna change your html structure if yes please let me know than i do it .

Answer (score 0):

Change the dark class top to 60%

CSS:

```
.dark{ top: 60%; }
```

And margin-left to 40px for image

CSS:

```
.img-responsive{ margin-left: 40px; }
```

or

```
.img-responsive{ margin-left: 7%; }
```

[image]

Comment: This is not true .you can test on the jsfiddle link on top of page

Comment: Attached the screenshot for your reference. Actually your image is placed after a form control and the image cannot overlap it unless you give absolute position values. What I did is, just shifted the overlay (dark class) down to center image in it. I hope that helped !!!

Comment: Reference :http://www.dnnskin.net/DesktopModules/ArtStore/Templates/ProductDetail/demo-295.html